# SwiftShield: Obfuscation using SwiftShield gives error

Tags: ios, swift, obfuscation

I want to obfuscate Swift code using [SwiftShield](https://github.com/rockbruno/swiftshield). I have integrated using Cocoapods.

To run it, I am using below SwiftShield tool in terminal:

```
swiftshield -automatic -project-root /app/MyApp -automatic-project-file 
/app/MyApp/MyApp.xcworkspace -automatic-project-scheme MyApp-AppStore
```

Getting error:

```
-bash: swiftshield: command not found
```

I have copied swiftshield executable from pods to /usr/local/bin and tried the same command, but still getting below error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/sourcekitd.framework/Versions/A/sourcekitd
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/swiftshield
Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

What could be the issue? How to install SwiftShield

Comment: Did you install swiftshield in the first place?

Comment: Yes using Cocoa-pods.

Comment: Swiftshield is not a cocoa pod.

Comment: Yes..I mean, I have integrated SwiftShield using dependency manager "Cocoapods". https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftShield  and running "swiftshield -automatic...." command from terminal.

Comment: Pods are not installed globally. So any executable wont be generally available in the command line. You need to run it from its location. probably somethign like `./Pods/SwiftShield/bin/swiftshield`

Comment: Yes..First I went to  /Pods/SwiftShield/ where swiftshield executable is resides. Still getting same error.

Comment: if your in the folder you need to call it like `./swiftshield` i think

Comment: @Scriptable Tried using ./swiftshield, Now getting error                                                                               dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/sourcekitd.framework/Versions/A/sourcekitd
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/swiftshield
Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6

Comment: I think you need to install swiftshield properly rather than using a pod

Comment: @Scriptable Is there any way to install swiftshield ? I tried with " brew install swiftshield", but getting error "Error: No available formula with the name "swiftshield""

Comment: download latest release from github, extract and install I guess, I'm not familiar with that library

Comment: https://github.com/rockbruno/swiftshield/issues/71#event-2832206369

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue was related with Xcode path. I had 2 Xcode versions were installed on my machine.

***/Applications/Xcode10.3.1.app***

***/Applications/Xcode11.1.app***

I deleted ***Xcode10.3.1.app*** and renamed ***Xcode11.1.app*** to ***Xcode.app***. Issue got resolved now.
https://github.com/rockbruno/swiftshield/issues/71#event-2832206369

**Steps to use swiftshield(Manual mode):**

1. Download swiftshield executable on desktop 
   https://github.com/rockbruno/swiftshield/releases
2. Command line - Go to desktop and give executable permission

```
sudo chmod 755 swiftshield
```

3. Move swiftshield executable to /usr/bin

```
sudo cp swiftshield /usr/local/bin
```

4. Check if it is installed properly

```
swiftshield --help
```

5. Change permission of project root folder in order to rename obfuscated code

```
chmod -R 774 ./ProjectRootDir
```

6. Obfuscate code using manual mode

```
swiftshield -project-root ./ProjectRootDir -tag __obf -verbose
```

Comment: In step 3, should we move the entire directory or any particular file?

Comment: @Sneha Only swiftshield executable

Comment: @GauravBorole In 3 step , Got error like-  cp: swiftshield is a directory (not copied).

Comment: @ChandanJee Make sure that you are copying executable not directory...

Comment: Does it work properly with 3rd party libraries added with xcode's "swift package manager"? I repeated step 5 several times, but always receive an error "You don’t have permission to save the file fileName in the folder packageName.....Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied"

Comment: I've just solved it. Just added permissions to DerivedData folder `chmod -R 774 user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectName`