# Can anyone explain how to obfuscate codebase using Swiftshield?

Tags: ios, swift, security, obfuscation

I have gone through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54304648/swiftshield-obfuscation-using-swiftshield-gives-error) but I am still not able to obfuscate full codebase.

I am using this command for the same:

```
swiftshield -automatic -project-root ../TestApp -automatic-project-file ../TestApp/DemoTestApp.xcworkspace -automatic-project-scheme DemoTestApp
```

Getting this error:

```
error: 'CustomButton' is unavailable: cannot find Swift declaration for this class
@IBOutlet weak var customButton: CustomButton!
                               ^~~~~~~~~~
DemoFramework.CustomButton:2:12: note: 'CustomButton' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
```

I have a `CustomButton` class that is in the custom framework.

Can anyone walk me step by step methods for how to use swiftshield for code obfuscation?
Thanks in advance. :)